# JPA deleting child removes parent

Tags: java, database, jpa, cascade

I have the following two entities:

```
    public class Parent implements Serializable
      @OneToMany(mappedBy="m_owner", targetEntity = Child.class, orphanRemoval=true)
      List<Child> children;
```

and

```
    public class Child implements Serializable
      @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Parent.class)
```

When I delete the Parent, the children are deleted as expected but when I delete the child, the Parent is removed. I tried adding the `cascade=CascadeType.DETACH` to the child's annotation but that did not help. How do I make it so deleting the children has no impact on the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was caused by the fact that I used a `NamedQuery` to delete the child.

```
@NamedQuery(name="Child.deleteById", query="Delete from Child child where child.m_id=:id")
```

This appears to circumvent the annotations I had set up and deleted the parent entity.

To solve this, I changed the delete service to simply use the `EntityManager.remove()` at which point all the annotations worked.